Unable to update PR with a verified commit created by createCommitOnBranch
My goal is to generate verified commits, using GitHub's Graphql API. I created a test repository to validate the verified PR creation, and I see the GitHub Action generating the new README.md file. However, it is not added to existing PR (link removed, see provided answer) in progress.
When the GitHub Action runs, I get the following error:
Switched to a new branch 'feature/verified-commit'
branch 'feature/verified-commit' set up to track 'origin/feature/verified-commit'.
time="2024-12-23T23:30:48Z" level=info msg="Found Chart directories [roles/argo-cd]"
time="2024-12-23T23:30:48Z" level=info msg="Generating README Documentation for chart roles/argo-cd"
-rw-r--r-- 1 runner docker 409 Dec 23 23:30 .github/api/commit.gql
error parsing " 'query" value: open .github/api/commit.gql': no such file or directory

Thank you for letting me know what I miss.

I ended-up using the GitHub GraphQL API with actions/github-script into workflow, instead of actually using the binary. The step handles properly both additions and deletions, with CreateCommitOnBranch mutation.
Previous implementation, without verified signature:

New implementation:

You can examine the actual PR with the new implementation.

You need to split flags (-F) and their values into separate elements to pass them correctly when expanded. This is how the step should look:
run: |
  git config user.email '${{ github.actor_id }}+${{ github.actor }}@users.noreply.github.com'
  git config user.name '${{ github.actor }}'
  git fetch
  git switch ${{ github.head_ref }}
  helm-docs --values-file=./defaults/main.yaml
  if [ -n "$(git ls-files -om --deduplicate)" ]; then
    declare -a params
    params+=("-F") 
    params+=("repository='${{ github.repository }}'")
    params+=("-F") 
    params+=("branchName='${{ github.head_ref }}'")
    params+=("-F") 
    params+=("oid='${{ github.event.pull_request.head.sha }}'")
    params+=("-F") 
    params+=("message='docs(github-action): update documentation'")
    mapfile -t clips < <(git ls-files -d --deduplicate)
    mapfile -t files < <(git ls-files -om --deduplicate)
    for file in "${files[@]}"; do
      type='addition'
      for clip in "${clips[@]}"; do
        if [ "$clip" == "$file" ]; then
          type='deletion'
        fi
      done
      params+=("-F") 
      params+=("fileChanges[][file][type]='$type'")
      params+=("-F") 
      params+=("fileChanges[][file][path]='$file'")
      if [ "$type" == 'addition' ]; then
        params+=("-F") 
        params+=("fileChanges[][file][contents]='$(base64 -w 0 $file)'")
      fi
    done
    params+=("-F") 
    params+=("query=@.github/api/commit.gql")
    echo "${params[@]}"
    gh api graphql "${params[@]}"
  fi


Actually, you don't. I moved away from gh api graphql binary usage, with a proper actions/github-script implementation. See the accepted answer.
